# Returning content of XML element

Tags: xml, bash, xpath, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to use xmlstarlet to extract the text in certain elements in this XML feed:

https://services.boatwizard.com/bridge/events/bc0af0c8-4b47-42b3-9a71-5326775344e0/boats?status=on

One of the elements I'd like to extract is the text for city name which is embedded in the XML document as (excluding certain parent elements for clarity):

```
<Location>
<LocationAddress>
<CityName>St Malo</CityName>
<CountryID>FR</CountryID>
<Postcode>35400</Postcode>
</LocationAddress>
</Location>
```

I'm trying to extract "St Malo".

I've saved the feed to `boats.xml` and I've used `xmlstarlet el -v boats.xml` to figure out the correct XPath name, which seems to be:

```
ProcessVehicleRemarketingDataArea/VehicleRemarketing/VehicleRemarketingBoatLineItem/Location/LocationAddress/CityName
```

I am trying the following syntax to extract the text:

```
xml sel -t -m "ProcessVehicleRemarketingDataArea/VehicleRemarketing/VehicleRemarketingBoatLineItem/Location/LocationAddress/CityName" -v "." -n boats.xml
```

Have tried many different syntax variations with no success. Almost think it might be the XML file that's off? How I extract "St Malo"?

Comment: How did you download the whole `xml` data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML in the link you supplied declares a default namespace in the `VehicleRemarking` tag:

```
 <VehicleRemarketing xmlns="http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5" ...>
```

That means you have to declare it with a prefix which you should use to qualify *each* step of your XPath expression that is part of that namespace:

```
xml sel -N ns=http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5 
        -t -m "ProcessVehicleRemarketingDataArea/ns:VehicleRemarketing//ns:CityName" 
        -v "." -n boats.xml
```

The first element is not part of the namespace, but `ns:VehicleRemarketing` and all its children are. You can also use just `//ns:CityName` for the expression, in this case (considering the example you posted - it will return *all* `CityName` elements in the file).

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually need a template match (the `-m` option), because the query is so simple in your case. Taking as input the portion of the XML document that you actually show in the question, using

```
$ xml sel -t -v "//CityName" -n boats.xml
```

will result in

```
St Malo
```

If the input document actually has namespaces, consider using

```
$ xml sel -t -v "//*[local-name() = 'CityName']" -n boats.xml
```

Or, even better, declare this namespace URI together with a prefix, see the answer by helderarocha.